# Stop user zooming in and out of webpage

Tags: html, css

Apart from user-scalable=no which doesn't prevent the user from changing size on desktop what are the best ways to prevent a user from being able to zoom in and out of a webpage?

Comment: You can't. There's this thing called accessibility... You might want to read up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there may be some approaches to handling this, such as Javascript-based plugins, you may want to consider your reasoning behind doing this as it brings up several accessibility concerns.

If you have users with poor vision or terribly low resolutions, they may need to view the site at 150-175% of its normal size. Instead of setting this limitation on the user and your application, [consider making your site or application responsive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) to accommodate these types of issues without preventing behavior that most users would commonly expect in a site.

Comment: 1) Webpage is not necessary a website. 2) Solution and moral teaching are different things. Here people need a solution.